# How to derive the moment of inertia of a thick rod?

Tags: integration

It is known that the moment of inertia of a thin rod about its center is
$$
I=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}r^{2}\,\frac{M}{L}{\rm d} r
=\frac{1}{12}ML^{2}
$$

However, how should I derive the moment of inertia of a thick rod $?$.

Comment: This question would be better asked at [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: On second thoughts, this is such a common question that you can find it by searching "moment of inertia of a cylinder about central diameter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thick rod can be modeled as a cylinder of height $h$, radius $R$, and density $\rho$. The moment of inertia (about the $y$ axis, say) will be $\int (x^2 + z^2) \rho dV$.

Computing this triple integral in cylindrical coordinates ($x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$, $z = z$) gives us

$\int \int \int (r^2 \cos^2 \theta + z^2) \rho r d\theta dr dz = \rho \int \int \int (r^2 \cos^2 \theta + z^2) r d\theta dr dz$

First, we calculate $\int \int \int z^2 r d\theta dr dr$, which evaluates to $\pi R^2 \frac{2 (h/2)^3}{3} = \frac{\pi R^2 h^3}{12}$.

Then, we calculate $\int\int\int r^2 \cos^2\theta r dr d\theta dz$, which works out to be $\frac{R^4}{4} \pi h$. So the total is $\frac{\pi R^2 h (h^2 + 3 R^2)}{12}$.

Multiplying by $\rho$ gives us $(\rho \pi R^2 h) \frac{h^2 + 3 R^2}{12} = M \frac{h^2 + 3 R^2}{12}$.

Let's check the "limiting cases". In the limiting case of $R = 0$, we see that this is $M \frac{h^2}{12}$, exactly the thin rod case.

In the limiting case of $h = 0$, we see that the result is $M \frac{R^2}{4}$. This is exactly the moment of spinning a disc about its diameter, which is basically what we're doing in this case.